# Is there a way to track how often an entity is getting hit in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to keep track of how often an entity is being hit by an elasticsearch hit.
For example, let's say I had an index like this:

```
{
    "company":"google"
},
{
    "company":"amazon"
},
{
    "company":"goodyear"
}
```

and I do a search query like "goo" that returns `google` and `goodyear`. Is there a way I can keep track over time of how often an entity is getting hit?
Something like

```
{
    "company":"google",
    "tracking_num_hits": 1
},
{
    "company":"amazon",
    "tracking_num_hits": 0
},
{
    "company":"goodyear",
    "tracking_num_hits": 1
}
```

and if I then search "amazon" it updates to

```
{
    "company":"google",
    "tracking_num_hits": 1
},
{
    "company":"amazon",
    "tracking_num_hits": 1
},
{
    "company":"goodyear",
    "tracking_num_hits": 1
}
```

Is there a way for elasticsearch to do this, and if not what is the best way to track this on the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to increment these tracking markers yourself, perhaps with an [`_update_by_query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) call as soon as you've obtained the hits:

```
POST myindex/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "company.keyword": [
        "google",
        "goodyear"
      ]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "if (ctx._source.tracking_num_hits != null) { ctx._source.tracking_num_hits++ } else { ctx._source.tracking_num_hits = 1 }"
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Hey btw I'm writing an elasticsearch handbook full of examples like this, plus other non-trivial, real-world use cases. You can [let me know](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) what you'd like to see in there and I'll let you know when it's out!

Comment: I've found that I can't add from/size to these updates, it will only update all hits. Is there a way I can add a max size to the number of docs I want to update?

Comment: Yes. The attribute is called [`max_docs`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-api-query-params).

Comment: @Brian I'm curious -- what's the use case of needing to further limit the subset of objects if the query already limits them? Just to try if the script works?

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage [Top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) for your use case. `top_hits` metric aggregator keeps track of the most relevant document being aggregated.

***`top hit`*** aggregation returns buckets of search hits. Generally, the top hit aggregation is used as a **subaggregation** so that the top matching documents can be *aggregated in buckets*.

**Example Query :**

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/sales/_search?size=0&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "aggs": {
    "top_tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type",
        "size": 3
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_sales_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "date": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": {
              "includes": [ "date", "price" ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```